# I have date in the format of [month1-month3 year] format, I wanna convert it to one month [month2 year], in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataset with data measured at all three months as shown in the picture below.
[image]

I want to change it such that instead of 'Mar-May 1992' it says 'Apr 1992' or '04-1992' Any of the two formats work.

My current code doesn't work, Here's the snippet:

```
def convert_date_format(date_str):
    start_month, end_month_year = date_str.split('-')
    end_month, year_str = end_month_year.split()
    month_dict = {'Jan': '01', 'Feb': '02', 'Mar': '03', 'Apr': '04', 'May': '05', 'Jun': '06',
                  'Jul': '07', 'Aug': '08', 'Sep': '09', 'Oct': '10', 'Nov': '11', 'Dec': '12'}
    
    # Get the numeric values for start and end months
    start_month_num = int(month_dict[start_month])
    end_month_num = int(month_dict[end_month])

    # Calculate the middle month
    middle_month_num = (start_month_num + end_month_num) // 2

    # Convert to the desired format
    return f"{month_dict[str(middle_month_num)]} {year_str}" 
       

# Apply the conversion to the 'Months' column in 'unemp_p_df' 
unemp_p_df['Months'] = unemp_p_df['Months'].apply(convert_date_format)
unemp_p_df.head()
```

Comment: Can you have an overlap over two different years? What would be the format?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the month range is always 3 months long and you want to keep the second one (i.e., for Mar-May you want to keep Apr), you can do the following:

```py
df.loc[:, "Months"] = df.loc[:, "Months"].str.split("-")
df.loc[:, "Months"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df.loc[:, "Months"].apply(lambda row: row[1])
) + pd.DateOffset(months=-1)
df.loc[:, "Months"] = df.loc[:, "Months"].apply(lambda row: row.strftime("%m-%Y"))
```

Result will be:

```
    Months    location
0  04-1992  North East  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, it looks like you want the middle of a 3 month period. You can do that by splitting the input on `-`, taking the second part, converting that to a datetime and subtracting 1 month and then re-formatting as required:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Months' : 
    ['Mar-May 1992', 'Apr-Jun 1992', 'May-Jul 1992', 'Jun-Aug 1992', 'Jul-Sep 1992']}
)

df['Months'] = (pd.to_datetime(
    df['Months'].str.split('-', expand=True)[1], format='%b %Y') + pd.DateOffset(months=-1)
    ).dt.strftime('%b %Y')
```

Output:

```
     Months
0  Apr 1992
1  May 1992
2  Jun 1992
3  Jul 1992
4  Aug 1992
```

To get `04-1992` and similar, just change the format string `%b %Y` to `%m-%Y`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost functional, your main issue was that you tried to use the same dictionary to convert back from numbers to month abbreviations. It's also unnecessary to set the month numbers as strings, directly use numbers.

Finally, note that this code would only work with periods that do not overlap two years (the format in such case is undefined), you can however easily adapt it if needed.

```
from calendar import month_abbr

month_dict = {k:v for v, k in enumerate(month_abbr[1:], start=1)}
# {'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, 'Apr': 4, 'May': 5, 'Jun': 6,
#  'Jul': 7, 'Aug': 8, 'Sep': 9, 'Oct': 10, 'Nov': 11, 'Dec': 12}

def convert_date_format(date_str):
    start_month, end_month_year = date_str.split('-')
    end_month, year_str = end_month_year.split()
    
    # Get the numeric values for start and end months
    start_month_num = month_dict[start_month]
    end_month_num = month_dict[end_month]

    # Calculate the middle month
    middle_month_num = (start_month_num + end_month_num) // 2

    # Convert to the desired format
    return f"{month_abbr[middle_month_num]} {year_str}" 
       

# Apply the conversion to the 'Months' column in 'unemp_p_df' 
unemp_p_df['Months'] = unemp_p_df['Months'].apply(convert_date_format)
```

Output (as new column for clarity):

```
         Months Months_out
0  Mar-May 1992   Apr 1992
1  Apr-Jun 1992   May 1992
2  May-Jul 1992   Jun 1992
3  Jun-Aug 1992   Jul 1992
4  Jul-Sep 1992   Aug 1992
5  Jan-May 1992   Mar 1992  # example with 5 months range
```